# Есть куча данных с лабораторного стенда. Как нарисовать красивые графики?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6, matplotlib

Есть куча данных с лабораторного стенда. 
Рисуем графики - проблема в одном из них. С ТЕ PE нет проблем.
Проблема с расходомерами - данные бывают и положительные и отрицательные,а 
на графике с FE непонятно что :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот код.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fn = r'D:\NET\log\22.08.2018\data.xlsx'

SMALL_SIZE = 12
MEDIUM_SIZE = 16
BIGGER_SIZE = 22

plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=SMALL_SIZE)     # fontsize of the axes title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # fontsize of the x and y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=BIGGER_SIZE)    # legend fontsize
plt.rc('figure', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)  # fontsize of the figure title

plt.style.use('ggplot')

p = Path(r'D:\NET\log\22.08.2018')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', header=None, usecols=[2,3,5],
                            names=['date','time',f.stem], index_col=['date','time'])
               for f in p.glob('*.trd')],
               axis=1)

df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0) + ' ' + df.index.get_level_values(1)))

df['Обороты'] = df['FREQ'] * 60

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(50, 70));

df.filter(regex=r'^TE').plot(ax=axes[0])

df.filter(regex=r'^PE').plot(ax=axes[1], sharex=True)

df.filter(regex=r'^FE').plot(ax=axes[2], sharex=True)

df.filter(regex=r'^TOK').plot(ax=axes[3])
ax_press1 = df.filter(regex=r'^Обороты').plot(ax=axes[3], secondary_y=True)

axes[-1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y'))

for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc='upper left')

axes[0].set_ylabel('Температура')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Давление')
axes[2].set_ylabel('Qv m3')
axes[3].set_ylabel('Ток двигателя')
ax_press1.set_ylabel('Обороты')
axes[-1].set_xlabel('Время')

df.to_excel(fn)
```

Вот данные - https://dropmefiles.com/hMgHm

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание на огромные отрицательные значения:

```
In [264]: df['FE2101'].max()
Out[264]: 48.032173

In [265]: df['FE2101'].min()
Out[265]: -1.757166556012362e+35   # <----------- NOTE !!!

In [263]: df.loc['2018-08-21 22:24:00':'2018-08-21 22:24:20', 'FE2101']
Out[263]:
2018-08-21 22:24:00    3.641180e+01
2018-08-21 22:24:01   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:02   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:03   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:04   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:05   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:06   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:07   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:08   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:09   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:10   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:11   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:12   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:13   -1.757167e+35
2018-08-21 22:24:14    2.602595e+00
2018-08-21 22:24:15    2.602595e+00
2018-08-21 22:24:16    2.602595e+00
2018-08-21 22:24:17    1.372858e+00
2018-08-21 22:24:18    1.372858e+00
2018-08-21 22:24:19    1.372858e+00
2018-08-21 22:24:20    1.336437e+00
Name: FE2101, dtype: float64
```

из `FE2101.trd`:

```
1534890239;80639007;2018-08-21;22:23:59;.fuel2;36.411797;.Q2;24.843061;
1534890240;80640007;2018-08-21;22:24:00;.fuel2;36.411797;.Q2;45.128777;
1534890241;80641007;2018-08-21;22:24:01;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;45.128777;
1534890242;80642007;2018-08-21;22:24:02;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;45.128777;
1534890243;80643007;2018-08-21;22:24:03;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;45.128777;
1534890244;80644007;2018-08-21;22:24:04;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;45.128777;
1534890245;80645007;2018-08-21;22:24:05;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;45.128777;
1534890246;80646007;2018-08-21;22:24:06;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;45.128777;
1534890247;80647007;2018-08-21;22:24:07;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;45.128777;
1534890248;80648007;2018-08-21;22:24:08;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;45.128777;
1534890249;80649007;2018-08-21;22:24:09;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;45.128777;
1534890250;80650007;2018-08-21;22:24:10;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;49.763813;
1534890251;80651007;2018-08-21;22:24:11;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;49.763813;
1534890252;80652007;2018-08-21;22:24:12;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;49.763813;
1534890253;80653007;2018-08-21;22:24:13;.fuel2;-175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000;.Q2;49.763813;
1534890254;80654007;2018-08-21;22:24:14;.fuel2;2.602595;.Q2;49.763813;
1534890255;80655007;2018-08-21;22:24:15;.fuel2;2.602595;.Q2;49.763813;
```

Обратите внимание на `1e35` в верхнем левом углу графика (`FE*`) - не удивительно что график выглядит подобным образом...

---

**UPDATE:**

можно "обнулить" (заполнить `NaN`) значения, которые по модулю больше 1000, перед рисованием графика:

```
import numpy as np

df[df.abs() > 1000] = np.nan
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так я видел :) - это сломанный датчик такое выдает....пока нет возможности исправить. Может как-то можно отфильтровать вывод по осям с пределами например от -1000 до +1000 ?

Comment: @Ivan, это не сложно. А что делать с полем `FEV3001` - там много значений в диапазоне `[7000, 8000)`?

Comment: наверное на отдельный граф вынесем. но там то де проскакивает минус дикий - отечественные расходомеры они такие отечественные :) может не NaN а как-то выцепить -175716655601236250000000000000000000.000000 - может быть по кол-ву знаков и уже потом на NaN заменить.

Comment: @Ivan, просто подставьте нужное число вместо 1000